# Input mask wildcards in a PLC language, i need to represent 4 characters

Tags: regex, input, wildcard, mask, plc

How do i use wildcards in my input mask in a PLC language (structured text)?

```
 ^^[0-9][0-9][A-Z][2][0]



    main()
    {
    barcodeData = getBarcode();

    if (match(barcodeData, "^^[0-1][0-9][2][0][P]*"))
        {do something
        }
    else{dosomethingelse
        }
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196297/discussion-on-question-by-teddy-input-mask-wildcards-in-a-plc-language-i-need-t).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a regular expression. There `*` is not a wildcard but a quantifier. It means that the preceding character or group can occur zero or more times. `.` is a wildcard. It means any character except newline. `[...]` is a character set. It means any character from the set.

`.` is a wildcard for one character.

`.*` is a wildcard for any number of characters.

`[.]` means exactly one dot.

`.{4}` means four wildcards.

You can use sandboxes and cheatsheets like https://regexr.com/ to test your regular expressions.